# Javascript Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I tried looking at the other questions regarding this error but they do not apply to my code.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="get">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">

  Favourite Sport: <select id="sport">
                     <option value=""> -- </option>
                     <option value="soccer"> Soccer </option>
             <option value="ball"> Basketball </option>
                   </select> <br />

  Lucky Number: <input type="number" name="number">

  Favourite Colour: <input type="text" name="colour"> <br />

  Favorite Animal: <select id="animal">
                     <option value=""> -- </option>
                     <option value="dog"> Dog </option>
                     <option value="cat"> Cat </option>
                     <option value="bunny"> Bunny </option>
                   </select>

  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  // store the sport select field as a variable
  var sportSelector = document.getElementById("sport");

  // get the selected value from the sport select field
  var sport = sportSelector.options[sportSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  var animalSelector = document.getElementById("animal");
  var animal = animalSelector.options[animalSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  var name = form1.name.value;
  var number = form1.number.value;
  var colour = form1.colour.value;

  console.log("Value of Inputs: " + name, sport, number, colour, animal);
  console.log(form1.getElementsByTagName("select").length);
  // variable to hold number of input fields, input tags + select tags, minus 1 to account for button
  var numInputFieldsTotal = form1.getElementsByTagName("input").length + form1.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

  var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  // same variable as above, but only counts inputs that have been filled out in for loop and does not count button value of Submit
  var numActiveInputFields = 0;

  for (var j=0; j < numInputFieldsTotal; j++) {
    if (inputFields[j].value != "" && inputFields[j].value != "Submit") {
      numActiveInputFields += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log("Active input fields: " + numActiveInputFields);

  // same process for select fields

  // all select fields
  var selectFields = form1.getElementsByTagName("select");

  // same variable as above to store active select fields, only counts filled out select inputs in for loop
  var numActiveSelectFields = 0; 

  for (var h=0; h < selectFields.length; h ++) {
    if (selectFields[h].value != "") {
      numActiveSelectFields += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log("Active Select Fields: " + numActiveSelectFields);

  // sum of total active input and select fields, minus 1 to account for button
  var sumActiveFields = numActiveInputFields + numActiveSelectFields;

  console.log("Sum of Active Fields: " + sumActiveFields);

  // store all inputs into an array
  var arrayInputs = [];
  for (var i=0; i < numActiveInputFields; i++) {
    // assign each input to a variable if input not empty and not submit (to avoid button value)
    if (inputFields[i].value != "" && inputFields[i].value != "Submit") {
      arrayInputs[i] = inputFields[i].value;
    }
  }

  console.log("Array of Input Values: " + arrayInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arrayInputs.length);

  // store all select inputs into an array
  var arraySelectInputs = [];
  for (var k=0; k < numActiveSelectFields; k++) {
    arraySelectInputs[k] = selectFields[k].value;
  }

  console.log("Array of Select Input Values: " + arraySelectInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arraySelectInputs.length);

  // combine the two arrays of regular inputs and select inputs
  arrayAllInputs = arrayInputs.concat(arraySelectInputs);
  console.log("Array of all inputs " + arrayAllInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arrayAllInputs.length);

  // variable to hold arrays of multiple usernames
  var usernames = [];

  // loop that combines all the inputs in a random order, number of times dictated by "q < x" where x represents the number of times
  for ( var q=0; q < 2; q++) {
    // initialize an array inside the username array
    usernames[q] = [];

    // keep adding to the inside array until all the inputs have been inserted
    while (usernames[q].length < arrayAllInputs.length) {

      // generate a random number to pick a random input
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayAllInputs.length);

      // if the input is not already in the inside array, add it 
      if (!usernames[q].includes(arrayAllInputs[random])) {
        usernames[q].push(arrayAllInputs[random]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(usernames[0], usernames[1]);

  var usernameStrings = [];
  // join inside arrays into strings, w < "x" x should be the same as the q < "X" from the above for loop
  for ( var w=0; w < 2; w ++) {
    usernameStrings[w] = usernames[w].join("");
  }
  console.log(usernameStrings);
}
```

So what I don't understand is that when error testing each individual input or select field they all return the correct values as seen in the line where each one is individually logged as its own value. None of them were undefined.

Prior to adding the 2nd select field (animal one), all the rest of the code works perfectly fine, yet the error message is pointing me to the input tag for loop not the select tag for loop. Any help would be appreciated.

The error message:

```
username_generator.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at myFunction (username_generator.html:55)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (username_generator.html:26)
```

Comment: You are trying to access name,number and color values like an object which "form1" is not. Declare it first. Fiddle would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things were missing. I hope below given points would help,

1. Need to define "form1"

   `var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");`
2. numInputFieldsTotal is assigned with additional Select input type which mismatches with the length of the total input fields in the form "inputFields" giving uncaught exception. Please remove assignment of select input type.

   `var numInputFieldsTotal = form1.getElementsByTagName("input").length - 1;`

Here's the link to my fiddle version.
https://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/3ksun59t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the form from somewhere !!

Change the prototype of the function to :

```
function myFunction(form1)
```

And pass the form through the `onsubmit` event :

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't make a difference. I don't think this was the issue because all the code works if I remove the 2nd select statement. I want to add more select statements so I want to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you defined `form1` anywhere in your Javascript code ?

Comment: I used lines like this: var selectFields = form1.getElementsByTagName("select"); in some instances, or in others document.whatever

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the value of the variable `form1` inside your code somewhere! Like:

`var form1 = document.getElementByID('form1');`

Answer (score 0):

check this code, i have some change it

```js
function myFunction() {
  // store the sport select field as a variable
  var sportSelector = document.getElementById("sport");

  // get the selected value from the sport select field
  var sport = sportSelector.options[sportSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  var animalSelector = document.getElementById("animal");
  var animal = animalSelector.options[animalSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  var name = form1.name.value;
  var number = form1.number.value;
  var colour = form1.colour.value;

  console.log("Value of Inputs: " + name, sport, number, colour, animal);
  console.log(form1.getElementsByTagName("select").length);
  // variable to hold number of input fields, input tags + select tags, minus 1 to account for button
  var numInputFieldsTotal = form1.getElementsByTagName("input").length + form1.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

  
  // same variable as above, but only counts inputs that have been filled out in for loop and does not count button value of Submit
  var numActiveInputFields = 0;

  var  index;

var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputFields.numInputFieldsTotal; ++index) {
     if (inputFields[index].value != "" && inputFields[index].value != "Submit") {
      numActiveInputFields += 1;
    }
}



  console.log("Active input fields: " + numActiveInputFields);

  // same process for select fields

  // all select fields
  var selectFields = form1.getElementsByTagName("select");

  // same variable as above to store active select fields, only counts filled out select inputs in for loop
  var numActiveSelectFields = 0; 

  for (var h=0; h < selectFields.length; h ++) {
    if (selectFields[h].value != "") {
      numActiveSelectFields += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log("Active Select Fields: " + numActiveSelectFields);

  // sum of total active input and select fields, minus 1 to account for button
  var sumActiveFields = numActiveInputFields + numActiveSelectFields;

  console.log("Sum of Active Fields: " + sumActiveFields);

  // store all inputs into an array
  var arrayInputs = [];
  for (var i=0; i < numActiveInputFields; i++) {
    // assign each input to a variable if input not empty and not submit (to avoid button value)
    if (inputFields[i].value != "" && inputFields[i].value != "Submit") {
      arrayInputs[i] = inputFields[i].value;
    }
  }

  console.log("Array of Input Values: " + arrayInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arrayInputs.length);

  // store all select inputs into an array
  var arraySelectInputs = [];
  for (var k=0; k < numActiveSelectFields; k++) {
    arraySelectInputs[k] = selectFields[k].value;
  }

  console.log("Array of Select Input Values: " + arraySelectInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arraySelectInputs.length);

  // combine the two arrays of regular inputs and select inputs
  arrayAllInputs = arrayInputs.concat(arraySelectInputs);
  console.log("Array of all inputs " + arrayAllInputs);
  console.log("Length of array: " + arrayAllInputs.length);

  // variable to hold arrays of multiple usernames
  var usernames = [];

  // loop that combines all the inputs in a random order, number of times dictated by "q < x" where x represents the number of times
  for ( var q=0; q < 2; q++) {
    // initialize an array inside the username array
    usernames[q] = [];

    // keep adding to the inside array until all the inputs have been inserted
    while (usernames[q].length < arrayAllInputs.length) {

      // generate a random number to pick a random input
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayAllInputs.length);

      // if the input is not already in the inside array, add it 
      if (!usernames[q].includes(arrayAllInputs[random])) {
        usernames[q].push(arrayAllInputs[random]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(usernames[0], usernames[1]);

  var usernameStrings = [];
  // join inside arrays into strings, w < "x" x should be the same as the q < "X" from the above for loop
  for ( var w=0; w < 2; w ++) {
    usernameStrings[w] = usernames[w].join("");
  }
  console.log(usernameStrings);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" method="get" name="form1">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">

  Favourite Sport: <select id="sport">
                     <option value=""> -- </option>
                     <option value="soccer"> Soccer </option>
             <option value="ball"> Basketball </option>
                   </select> <br />

  Lucky Number: <input type="number" name="number">

  Favourite Colour: <input type="text" name="colour"> <br />

  Favorite Animal: <select id="animal">
                     <option value=""> -- </option>
                     <option value="dog"> Dog </option>
                     <option value="cat"> Cat </option>
                     <option value="bunny"> Bunny </option>
                   </select>

  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

hope it will help you